# Why can't I use xpath to parse nodes in the default namespace?

Tags: c++, xml, msxml

I'm an XML newbie and I have an XML document (which I can't edit because it comes from somewhere else) but it has a root node like this:

```
<Configuration xmlns="http://schemas.mycomp.com/product/settings" version="2.0.0">
```

I'm trying to parse this document with msxml and xpath and I've done it successfully if I remove the xmlns attribute.  For some reason, with this xmlns attribute in place, the document won't parse.  I've attempted to set the msxml parse to recognise the document using:

```
m_pXMLDoc->setProperty( _bstr_t(L"AllowDocumentFunction"), _variant_t(true));   
m_pXMLDoc->setProperty( _bstr_t(L"AllowXsltScript"), _variant_t(true));
m_pXMLDoc->setProperty( _bstr_t(L"SelectionLanguage"), _variant_t(L"XPath"));   
m_pXMLDoc->setProperty( _bstr_t(L"SelectionNamespaces"), _variant_t(L"xmlns='http://schemas.mycomp.com/product/settings'"));

m_pXMLDoc->preserveWhiteSpace = VARIANT_FALSE;
m_pXMLDoc->resolveExternals = VARIANT_TRUE; 
m_pXMLDoc->validateOnParse = VARIANT_FALSE;
```

From reading around it looks like xpath only works on the "no name" namespace and this document sets the default namespace so that it's no longer "no name".  Can I set the namespace that xpath uses using MSXML?

Comment: Hmm, I've noticed that if I edit the XML file and change the xmlns attribute to xmlns:x="http://schemas.mycomp.com/product/settings" then the document parses just fine.  I guess it's something to do with the elements being in the default namespace that's causing me problems...

Comment: Don't forget to include x: in your XPath expression in this case.
/x:Element will still match <Element xmlns="http://schemas.mycomp.com/product/settings">, while /Element will match two things: <Element> with a default namespace and <Element> with no namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Microsoft : This behaviour is by design ...

See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/288147

Use prefixes with the namespaces when you specify the SelectionNamespaces property

Comment: Yes, I feared this was the case.  Sadly not a great answer if you need to parse someone elses XML though :-(